# Como usar projeto android em Gradle no eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

Estou querendo incorporar esse projeto: https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button na minha aplicação android no eclipse, porém eu não uso gradle. Existe alguma forma de importá-lo sem gradle?

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é meio antiga, mas não custa responder :-)

Como você tem acesso ao código fonte (visto que é open source), você poderia gerar um Jar a partir do projeto (via gradle) e depois copiar o Jar na sua pasta de bibliotecas. É importante ser via gradle para ele criar um jar que contenha todas as dependencias desse projeto que você quer usar.

[O processo para criar um jar está descrito aqui.](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)

Eu desaconselho fortemente essa solução pois gerenciar dependencias "na mão" nunca é uma boa idéia. Se o seu projeto é de estudo ou algo do genero isso não será um problema, mas qualquer coisa além disso você terá (serios) problemas no futuro.